# Ubuntu virtualization with Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

On ubuntu 11.04 I created a virtual machine with Windows 7. Now at /home/username folder I have both ISO image of Windows and a folder with the system created by VirtualBox. The question is can I delete ISO image and will it affect virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

A virtual machine behaves similar to an actual machine

> A virtual machine (VM) is a software implementation of a machine (i.e.
>   a computer) that executes programs like a physical machine.
>   -[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)

So similar to an actual machine when you finish installing an operating system, you remove the disc, likewise, after you have installed Windows 7 you can remove the disk by

> *Select your Windows 7 VM* > Machine > Settings > Storage > *Select
>   Disc Drive* > *Click on the CD icon* > Remove disk from virtual drive

Then you can delete the `.iso` file and it will not affect your virtual machine.